# Model Binding - Cascading relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

hi Consider the following three classes that have a cascading relationship

```
public class Specification
{
    public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
public class Feature
{
    public int? SpecificationId { get; set; }
    public Specification Specification { get; set; }
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FeatureValue>  FeatureValues { get; set; }
}
 public class FeatureValue
{
    public int? FeatureId { get; set; }
    public Feature  Feature { get; set; }
    public int FeatureValueId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

In the next step and in a form, I read and display the information related to the above classes (from the database)
Like the following code snippet:

```
 @foreach (var specification in Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications)
                            {
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>  @specification.Caption</legend>

                                    @foreach (var feature in specification.Features)
                                    {
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="Specification_@(specification.SpecificationId)__Feature_@(feature.FeatureId)__FeatureValues">@feature.Caption :</label>
                                            <select name="Specifications[@specification.SpecificationId].Feature[@feature.FeatureId].FeatureValues"
                                                    id="Specification_@(specification.SpecificationId)__Feature_@(feature.FeatureId)__FeatureValues"
                                                    @(feature.IsMultipleChoices ? "multiple" : null)
                                                    data-multiple="@(feature.IsMultipleChoices?"true":"false")"
                                                    
                                                  
                                                    class="sffv-select form-control"
                                                    >
                                                <option></option>
                                                @foreach (var featureValue in feature.FeatureValues)
                                                {
                                                    <option value="@featureValue.FeatureValueId">
                                                        @featureValue.Caption
                                                    </option>
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                             </div>
                                    }
                                </fieldset>
                            }
```

Finally, I send the form information to the server, something like the following code snippet:

```
 $.ajax({
            async: true,
            data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
            type: "Post",
            url: "@FormUrl",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            success: function () {
                alert("Submitted!");
            }
        });
```

Something like this will be sent at the end:

[image]

My question is how should I get this model on the server side?
In addition, the IDs inside the bracket are required to store information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the following sample and use Asp.net Core Tag helper to display the model properties.

Add the following View Models to display data in the View:

```
public class SpecificationViewModel
{
    public List<SpecificationVM> Specifications { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificationVM
{
    public int SpecificationId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public List<FeatureVM> Features { get; set; }
}
public class FeatureVM
{
    public int? SpecificationId { get; set; }
    public Specification Specification { get; set; }
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsMultipleChoices { get; set; }     // Whether the <select> element is multiple select or single select.
    public List<int> selectedFeatureValue { get; set; }  // used to store the selected FeatureValueId.
    public List<FeatureValueVM> FeatureValues { get; set; }
}
public class FeatureValueVM
{
    public int? FeatureId { get; set; }
    public Feature Feature { get; set; }
    public int FeatureValueId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public SpecificationController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {  
        //query database and set value for the ViewModel.
        List<SpecificationViewModel> items = new List<SpecificationViewModel>()
        {
            new SpecificationViewModel(){ Specifications= _context.Specifications.Include(c=>c.Features).ThenInclude(c=>c.FeatureValues)
            .Select(c=>new SpecificationVM()
            {
                 SpecificationId = c.SpecificationId,
                 Caption = c.Caption,
                 Features = c.Features.Select(d=> new FeatureVM()
                 {
                      Caption = d.Caption,
                       IsMultipleChoices = d.IsMultipleChoices,
                        FeatureId = d.FeatureId,
                         Specification =d.Specification,
                          SpecificationId = d.SpecificationId,
                         FeatureValues = d.FeatureValues.Select(v=> new FeatureValueVM()
                         {
                              Caption = v.Caption,
                               FeatureValueId = v.FeatureValueId,
                               FeatureId = v.FeatureId,
                               Feature =v.Feature
                         }).ToList()
                 }).ToList()
            }).ToList() }
        };

        return View(items);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveSpecification(SpecificationViewModel model)
    {

        return Ok("success");
    }
```

View Page:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.SpecificationViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
 

<form id="MyForm">

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications.Count; i++)
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Caption</legend>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Caption" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].SpecificationId" />
            @for (var f = 0; f < Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features.Count; f++)
            {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].Caption :</label>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].Caption" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].FeatureId" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].SpecificationId" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].IsMultipleChoices" />

                <select asp-for="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].selectedFeatureValue"
                        asp-items='new SelectList(Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].FeatureValues, "FeatureValueId", "Caption")'
                        data-multiple="@Model.FirstOrDefault().Specifications[i].Features[f].IsMultipleChoices"
                        class="sffv-select form-control">
                    <option></option>
                </select> 
            </div>
            }
        </fieldset>
    }

    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>

@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {

            //loop through the <select> element,  add or remove multiple attribute from the <select> element
            $(".sffv-select").each(function (index, item) {
                if ($(item).attr("data-multiple") == "True") {
                    $(item).attr("multiple", "multiple");
                }
                else {
                    $(item).removeAttr("multiple");
                }
            });

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Specification/SaveSpecification", //change the url to yours
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function () {
                    alert("Submitted!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

After submitting the form, in the Post Method, you could loop through the ViewModel and get all selected value (selectedFeatureValue), then, according to them to find the related FeatureValue and do something. The result like this:

[image]